# How to make this website responsive using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, html-table, responsive

I would like to know how to make this HTML site responsive. It contains many iframes grouped into one table.

First, the main page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="width:200%;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><iframe name="mainframe" src="youtube cover art.jpg" width="1345" height="720"></iframe></td>
      <th style="width:10px;"> </th>
      <th style="width:446px;height:215px;font-size:40px;">Apps</th>
      <th style="width:446px;height:215px;font-size:40px;">An overview for the day</th>
      <th style="width:446px;height:215px;font-size:40px;">Settings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:10px;"> </th>
      <td><iframe src="apps 1.html" width="446" height="500"></iframe></td>
      <td><iframe src="http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/asia/rss.xml" width="446" height="500"></iframe></td>
      <td><iframe src="settings 1.html" width="446" height="500"></iframe></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

the iframe with apps 1.html as the src

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="width:425px;">
<a href="about:blank" target="mainframe">blank</a>
<a href="youtube cover art.jpg" target="mainframe">wallpaper</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="mainframe"><img src="youtube.jpg"></a>
<a href="http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/asia/rss.xml" target="mainframe"><img src="BBC News.jpg"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

and the iframe with settings 1.html as the src

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var password = "Hudson1377";
  var x = prompt("Enter in the password "," ");
  if (x!== password) {
   alert("Please try again.");
   window.location.reload();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body style="width:445px;">
<a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href">log out</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media Queries for that make sure to use min-width and max-width property and break point should follow this grid standard.
xs: 0,
sm: 480px,
md: 768px,
lg: 1024px

Comment: So this is what I have to do
`@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  #mainframe {width: 446px;}
}`
Am I correct?

Comment: it would be good if you just use min or max-width rather than just only width.

Answer (score -2):

Bicycle reinvention ?
Use Bootstrap and other available libraries or frameworks

Comment: Can you explain how to use bootstrap @Mostafa .m ?